# <div> length to automaticly fit the content length

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have `<h1>Some Headline</h1>` tag that is inside div. How do I accomplish so that div that contains this tag automatically resizes to fit the length of the tag element? I tried auto, but it fills entire space (width) inside another div that it's in.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="headline">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.headline {
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please post some CSS and HTML code.

Comment: `float: left;` or `display: table;`

Answer (score 2):

Just set `display: inline-block;` on div

```css
.title {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3>Some Headline</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add some text to `.title`, it goes on the same line. Not sure but I don't think that's the desired result.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I didn't play with "block" attributes alot, so I don't know alot about them. :)

Comment: @NenadVracar I meant *after `.title`* https://jsfiddle.net/u8wps5fw/1/ Anyway, It *might* be the desired output, and a quick solution is to put the content inside a `display: block` element.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But what do you think about the `table` display? Because in such situations usually I use `table`, not `inline-block`.

Comment: @Al.G `table` is great but for this particular example i think its too much and i would just use `inline-block`.